# Desktop icons randomly disappear - 16.10

Tags: icons, ubuntu-mate, desktop-icons

I installed Ubuntu onto my computer a few weeks ago.  After some updates at the beginning of this week - almost all web browsers 'broke' - all sites reported that I couldn't access them due to HSTS problems (Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Vivaldi, and Chromium wouldn't access sites like; Google, Bing, Yahoo, Microsoft, CNN, Ubuntu, etc).   The only browser that was still working was QupZilla.  I was able to resolve this by uninstalling Firefox and Chrome and then re-installing them.

Now all the browsers are working fine, but another issue started at the same time: randomly when I click on the menus at the top of the screen (running Mate), random desktop icons will disappear - I have about 20 icons, but usually at least a few remain.  Rebooting does restore the icons.  One time when they disappeared, I tried recreating a couple - they refused to show up, but when after rebooting I had duplicates on the screens.

The magically disappearing icons problem still persists - any ideas?